# What is the best way to format a dyanmic page so the user can print it?

Tags: php, html, css, printing

basically I'm wondering how/if it's possible to hit a print button and then print a dynamic page. So for example I've got a dynamic page which allows the user to view a particular vehicle with all it's information. I want the user to be able to hit 'Print' and it pushes all that data into a page that all fits onto 1 A4 bit of page and looks nice, instead when I hit 'Print Page' at the moment it's like 4 pages and the styling is all weird.

I have already tried the HTMLtoCANVAS but that didn't seem to work (maybe I set it up wrong...)

Hopefully the end result will be that the user can print a nice single A4 piece of paper with the vehicle details that they want on there.

Comment: You can use `@media print` CSS3 to format the page for printing differently than it is shown in the browser